# How to solve OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect error in pycharm

Tags: python, django

I'm new at django and immediately i try to edit the web application and run the server I get the error message below on my terminal, please help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\W\PycharmProjects\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\manageme
nt\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\W\PycharmProjects\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\manageme
nt\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\W\PycharmProjects\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\manageme
nt\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\pathlib.py", 
line 1168, in stat

return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label 
syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

I expect the output Hello World on my web application page

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There seems to be some part missing from your traceback. after `File "C:\Users\W` there's no closing `"`

Comment: This kind of error might mean that there's something wrong in your `INSTALLED_APPS` part of your django settings.py. Check that there's no typos in the list of apps, and also that you have not forgotten any commas between app names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be in your .urls especially if you were following the Django documentation, copying the code snippets and forgot to change the URL details to match your application settings.

In my case, for example, I had this:

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('crime_system/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Instead of:

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('crime_system/', include('crime_system.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will fix you original issue, however, at a minimum, you should check the way that you've indicated your Installed_apps:

See Django Docs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

And develop the habit of redacting your SECRET_KEY.

Answer (score 0):

This is the settings.py file

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'g_we0w^3!=y@rk40#m1+$luf!wc8d%x#*mekm#*z@g-vv^zowo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.genres',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoproject.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password- 
validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem. Turns out that after updating python, django-mptt and xlrd modules had for some reason become uninstalled. Reinstalled them with pip and everything works now.

So you should check your installed modules and reinstall if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the urls.py file that you created is in the correct place... I had a similar error, error and it turned out that I had created the urls.py outside the app directory.

Answer (score -1):

As we have tried all the debugging process but nothing work, maybe you need to delete this project ans start a new one following the steps on this tutorial.
[Django Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmljXZIypDc&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p)

Comment: When i type python3 manage.py runserver it tells me python3 is not a recognised command. But i have posted my settings.py file

Comment: Is this all the settings.py file ? Because it miss the templates and the database section, i will add it to my answer.

Comment: what is the name of your application that you have installed using python manage.py startapp ?

Comment: The name of the app is "genre" without the double quotes

Comment: ok you have to add it to the list of your INSTALLED_APPS like this "genre" with the double quotes

Comment: It's not working, should I re install django again?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the most useful django tutorial that you may find online.

Comment: I started a new project, followed your recommendations step by step and now it finally works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad that it worked, that guys have awsome tutorials i advise you to check them all it helped me with my debut with django